# JavaScript Array Sort with Mixed Value Types - Looking for Appropriate Compare Function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

Please refer to the table below.

**My objective is to sort a JavaScript array which contains mixed data types**: numbers, strings, booleans, dates, and undefined values.

This is NOT a natural sort. Instead, I need to **match the sorting order that MS Excel uses**... as closely as possible.

This is a JavaScript ES5 question, but the data are coming from Excel via an array in VBA.

The platform is the MS WebBrowser Control (IE11) hosted in an Excel VBA UserForm.

This is fairly esoteric, I know, but hopefully, the ultimate question is not.

Microsoft's flavor of JavaScript has a language extension called, the [VBArray Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/VBArray) which has a method that can be used to convert a passed VB safe array into a normal JavaScript array:

```
function convertVBArray(safearray){return new VBArray(safearray).toArray()}
```

The `.toArray()` method does the conversion, including the data type conversions for each element. The VBA array is of type Variant (a tagged union), which supports many different variable data subtypes. The `.toArray()` method does the work of converting these to JavaScript's more limited palette of data types.

The table below shows 23 values. Imagine them in a column in Excel. I populate the VBA variant array from that column (which looks like what you see in the `Excel Displays` column in the table below.

The next two columns show what the data look like once inside the VBA array.

The next three columns show what the data look like once converted to the JavaScript array with `convertVBArray()`.

Next, I use the following compare function to sort the JavaScript array:

```
a.sort(function (a, b) { return isNaN(a) ? isNaN(b) ? a.localeCompare(b) : 1 : isNaN(b) ? -1 : parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b) })
```

...but this does not work well.

Please refer to the `JS sortArray()` column of the table below. The data are presented in the order returned after the above sort.

***I am looking for an alteration to the compare function*** so that it sorts as closely as possible to the next column in the table, `Excel Sort ASC`.

Finally, I'd like to also be able to mimic the reverse sort as shown in the last column, `Excel Sort DESC`.

I realize that the various error values get converted to `undefined` values in JavaScript and that there's probably nothing that can be done about that. I do like that they all end up at the bottom of the sorted list.

---

In summary, I want the values from `Excel Displays` to be sorted by JavaScript in the order shown in `Excel Sort ASC`. But my current compare function produces the poor ordering found in `JS sortArray()`.

***My current compare function fails to sort in the order needed***.

.

The following table depicts how the data and data types change as they are passed from Excel to VBA to JavaScipt and back to Excel.

```
+-----+---------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Row | Excel Entered |     Excel Number Format      | Excel Displays  |    VBA Array Value    | VBA Array Value Type | JS Array Ndx |                       JS Array Value                       | JS Array Value typeof | JS sortArray() | Excel Sort ASC  | Excel Sort DESC |
+-----+---------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   1 | anchorage     | General                      | anchorage       | anchorage             | 8 - vbString         |            0 | anchorage                                                  | string                | -78.96         | -78.96          | #NAME?          |
|   2 | 123           | General                      | 123             | 123                   | 5 - vbDouble         |            1 | 123                                                        | number                | 123            | -1              | #N/A            |
|   3 | FALSE         | General                      | FALSE           | False                 | 11 - vbBoolean       |            2 | false                                                      | boolean               | FALSE          | 0               | #DIV/0!         |
|   4 | =qqq          | General                      | #NAME?          | Error 2029            | 10 - vbError         |            3 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | -1             | 0.60625         | TRUE            |
|   5 | 0             | 0.000_);[Red](0.000)         | 0               | 0                     | 5 - vbDouble         |            4 | 0                                                          | number                | 0              | 1               | FALSE           |
|   6 | 43514.49663   | m/d/yyyy h:mm                | 2/18/2019 11:55 | 2/18/2019 10:59:03 AM | 7 - vbDate           |            5 | Mon Feb 18 2019 11:59:09 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)  | date                  | 43514.49663    | 99.01           | zimmer          |
|   7 | =NA()         | General                      | #N/A            | Error 2042            | 10 - vbError         |            6 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 0.60625        | 123             | Major Tom       |
|   8 | 99.01         | $#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00) | 99.01           | 99.01                 | 6 - vbCurrency       |            7 | 99.01                                                      | number                | 1              | 3/20/2017       | anchorage       |
|   9 |               | General                      |                 |                       | 0 - vbEmpty          |            8 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 99.01          | 2/18/2019 11:55 | ABC             |
|  10 | =1/0          | General                      | #DIV/0!         | Error 2007            | 10 - vbError         |            9 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 888.87         |                 | 888.87          |
|  11 | =""           | General                      |                 |                       | 8 - vbString         |           10 |                                                            | string                |                | $%^%$^          | $%^%$^          |
|  12 | ABC           | @                            | ABC             | ABC                   | 8 - vbString         |           11 | ABC                                                        | string                | TRUE           | 888.87          |                 |
|  13 | -78.96        | General                      | -78.96          | -78.96                | 5 - vbDouble         |           12 | -78.96                                                     | number                | 42814          | ABC             | 2/18/2019 11:55 |
|  14 | Major Tom     | @                            | Major Tom       | Major Tom             | 8 - vbString         |           13 | Major Tom                                                  | string                | $%^%$^         | anchorage       | 3/20/2017       |
|  15 | TRUE          | General                      | TRUE            | True                  | 11 - vbBoolean       |           14 | true                                                       | boolean               | ABC            | Major Tom       | 123             |
|  16 | =TODAY()-700  | m/d/yyyy                     | 3/20/2017       | 3/20/2017             | 7 - vbDate           |           15 | Mon Mar 120 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time) | date                  | anchorage      | zimmer          | 99.01           |
|  17 | zimmer        | General                      | zimmer          | zimmer                | 8 - vbString         |           16 | zimmer                                                     | string                | Major Tom      | FALSE           | 1               |
|  18 | 1             | General                      | 1               | 1                     | 5 - vbDouble         |           17 | 1                                                          | number                | zimmer         | TRUE            | 0.60625         |
|  19 |               | General                      |                 |                       | 0 - vbEmpty          |           18 | undefined                                                  | undefined             |                | #NAME?          | 0               |
|  20 | =0-1          | General                      | -1              | -1                    | 5 - vbDouble         |           19 | -1                                                         | number                |                | #N/A            | -1              |
|  21 | 0.60625       | h:mm                         | 0.60625         | 0.60625               | 5 - vbDouble         |           20 | 0.60625                                                    | number                |                | #DIV/0!         | -78.96          |
|  22 | ="888.87"     | General                      | 888.87          | 888.87                | 8 - vbString         |           21 | 888.87                                                     | string                |                |                 |                 |
|  23 | $%^%$^        | General                      | $%^%$^          | $%^%$^                | 8 - vbString         |           22 | $%^%$^                                                     | string                |                |                 |                 |
+-----+---------------+------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Here is just the JavaScript array and target sort order:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| JS Array Ndx |                       JS Array Value                       | JS Array Value typeof | TARGET SORT ORDER |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|            0 | anchorage                                                  | string                | -78.96            |
|            1 | 123                                                        | number                | -1                |
|            2 | false                                                      | boolean               | 0                 |
|            3 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 0.60625           |
|            4 | 0                                                          | number                | 1                 |
|            5 | Mon Feb 18 2019 11:59:09 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)  | date                  | 99.01             |
|            6 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 123               |
|            7 | 99.01                                                      | number                | 3/20/2017         |
|            8 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | 2/18/2019 11:55   |
|            9 | undefined                                                  | undefined             |                   |
|           10 |                                                            | string                | $%^%$^            |
|           11 | ABC                                                        | string                | 888.87            |
|           12 | -78.96                                                     | number                | ABC               |
|           13 | Major Tom                                                  | string                | anchorage         |
|           14 | true                                                       | boolean               | Major Tom         |
|           15 | Mon Mar 120 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time) | date                  | zimmer            |
|           16 | zimmer                                                     | string                | false             |
|           17 | 1                                                          | number                | true              |
|           18 | undefined                                                  | undefined             | undefined         |
|           19 | -1                                                         | number                | undefined         |
|           20 | 0.60625                                                    | number                | undefined         |
|           21 | 888.87                                                     | string                | undefined         |
|           22 | $%^%$^                                                     | string                | undefined         |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Could you add another table to your question with the expected behavior? Meaning, what would you like the table to look like after sorting.

Comment: I'm not trying to sort the table. Just the values in the 4th column which is titled "Excel Displays." I want the sort list to match the 2nd-from-last column ("Excel Sort ASC").

Comment: The various table columns are just there to show how the data and data types change as they are passed from Excel to VBA to JavaScipt and back to Excel.

Comment: Are you able to show the Javascript array, and the expected sorted Javascript array.  All the VB stuff seems to be clouding the question slightly.

Comment: @ShyAgam I updated the question.

Comment: @Keith I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is something like what your after.

In your JS Array Value typeOf, it's saying date is a type date, but in normal Javascript `typeof new Date()` would give you object, so in your case you might want to change to `date`.

What I have done here is create a compound sort, first we sort by the `typeof`,  if both a & b are of the same type you get a return value of 0, this is were you do the second part of the compound sort, you are guaranteed here that a & b are of the same type, so just do the appropriate sort depending on type.

Below is a working snippet you can run to see the result.

```js
var data = [
 "anchorage",
  123,
  false,
  undefined,
  0,
  new Date("Mon Feb 18 2019 11:59:09 GMT-0800"),
  undefined,
  99.01,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  "",
  "ABC",
  -78.96,
  "Major Tom",
  true,
  new Date("Mon Mar 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700"),
  "zimmer",
  1,
  undefined,
  -1,
  0.60625,
  "888.87",
  "$%^%$^"    
];

//what ordering do we want our types?.
var typesort = [
  "number", "object" /*date*/, "string", "boolean", "undefined"
];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
  //first lets sort by type
  var r = typesort.indexOf(typeof a) - typesort.indexOf(typeof b);
  if (r === 0) {
    //types are the same, need compound sort
    if (typeof a === "object") return a.getTime() - b.getTime()
    else if (typeof a === "string") return a.localeCompare(b)
    else return a - b;
  }
  return r;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You are pretty close. I updated the array definition in your answer to include a couple of missed data items. The sorting is now done in the correct order. I understand what you are saying about the dates, but I'm concerned about that. Give me a moment to run a couple of tests...

Comment: You nailed it! Regarding the dates... it is interesting. The toArray() method works with data from the VB safearray and converts each element to data types that IE11's JavaScript engine is happy with. The type for the converted dates is absolutley 'date' and not 'object'. Simply replacing object with date in your typesort array did the trick. My only issue left is the error values. Can you think of any way to include them? I can't since the toArray() method converts them to 'undefined' Once that's done, JavaScript no longer has any information to work with.

Comment: Can you make this so that it also allows for sorting in descending order that matches the first table column, `Excel Sort DESC`?

Comment: @ExcelHero  Yes, once the information is lost, there is little we can do in Javascript.   For descending, you should be able to just do `data.reverse()` after doing the sort.  Alternatively you could inverse the comparitors, but in Javascript undefined will always go to the end in a sort, so `data.reverse()` would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but here's a solution using lodash.

```js
var values = [
    "anchorage",
    123,
    false,
    undefined,
    0,
    new Date("Mon Feb 18 2019 11:59:09 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"),
    undefined,
    99.01,
    undefined,
    undefined,
    "",
    "ABC",
    -78.96,
    "Major Tom",
    true,
    new Date("Mon Mar 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)"),
    "zimmer",
    1,
    undefined,
    -1,
    0.60625,
    "888.87",
    "$%^%$^"
]

var typesAsc = ["number", "date", "string", "boolean", "undefined"]


var typeOfValue = function (v) { return v instanceof Date ? "date" : typeof v }

var sortAsc = function (arr) {
    return _.orderBy(arr, _.identity, "asc")
}

var sortDesc = function (arr) {
    return _.orderBy(arr, _.identity, "desc")
}

var flattenInOrder = function (groups, ordering) {
    return _(ordering).map(function (type) { return groups[type] })
                      .flatten()
                      .value()
}

var valuesByType = _.groupBy(values, typeOfValue)

var valuesAscByType = _.mapValues(valuesByType, sortAsc)
var valuesAsc = flattenInOrder(valuesAscByType, typesAsc)
console.log(valuesAsc)

var valuesDescByType = _.mapValues(valuesByType, sortDesc)
var valuesDesc = flattenInOrder(valuesDescByType, typesAsc.reverse())
console.log(valuesDesc)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I'm familiar with VB, but if you just want ASC and DESC ordering, I would

```
// slice on desc as to not affect asc
var asc = new VBArray(yourArray).toArray(), desc = asc.slice().reverse();
```